# C# get the position of a whitespace before a special char

Tags: c#, string, substring, indexof

I am trying to extract the FPS count from a string.
This string and the FPS count can be of different structure and length.

Two Examples would be:

```
"  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 480x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 868 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 11988 tbn (default)"
"  Stream #0:0: Video: msmpeg4v3 (MP43 / 0x3334504D), yuv420p, 320x240, 744 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 29.97 tbn"
```

The only constant for getting the location of the FPS count is the " fps" and the ", " part in front of the number in the string.

I can get the location of the " fps" with this: `processOutput.IndexOf(" fps")`.

But because the FPS count can be of different length, I can not use this:
`processOutput.Substring(fpslocation - 5, 5);`

Is there a way to get the position of the ", " part before the number? Then I could take that as start index and the position of the " fps" part as end index.
Or can this value be filtered out even more easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regular expession for this:

```
var match = Regex.Match(input, @"[\d\.]+(?= fps)")
```

will look for a sequence of digits and decimal points (`[\d\.]+`) followed by " fps"; the latter not being included in the match.

`match.Value` will then contain the number.

Comment: It can be also helpful to add word boundaries in your regex like `[\d\.]+ (?=\bfps\b)`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a pattern with a capture group, and get the group value.

```
\b([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?) fps\b
```

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?` Match 1+ digits 0-9 with an optional decimal part
- `)` Close group 1
- `fps` Match literally
- `\b` A word boundary

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AwZJhc/1) and a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/EBX5KZ).

For example

```
string s = "  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 480x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 868 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 11988 tbn (default)";
Match m = Regex.Match(s, @"\b([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?) fps\b");
if (m.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Output

```
29.97
```